# Chrome css percentage

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

The problem is simple, webkit (or at least chrome) handle some percentage value badly.

For example if I have an overall div with a width of `450px`, if I had it two child with a width value of `7.117%` and `7.118%`, the output will be two div with a respective width of `31px` and `32px`. ([Fiddle of a test case](http://jsfiddle.net/rTVKa/))

Or a calculus shows that the calculated width value of **both** div is (in theory) above `32px`. The results are 32.0265 and 32.031. So that doesn't appear to be a subpixel problem as rounding down both value is rounding them to 32.

I was wondering if there were any workaround/best practice or else to deal with it.

Comment: I see 32px for both in your example.

Comment: Wah, that's weird. what's your chrome version? (And OS?)

Comment: +1 mainly for a thoroughly and properly done sample.

Comment: Like Amit, I can't reproduce the problem with Chromium 13.0.782.107 on Linux (oops, looks like I need to update ;) ). @ Py, whats yours?

Comment: @Py: Chrome 15.0.854.0 on Ubuntu 11.04/64-bit gets 32px for both

Comment: Version 13.0.782.112 on Windows here.

Comment: 11.0.696.57 on Unix 64 bits (looks like i need to update).
I was also able to reproduce it on the default browser of an atrix (i don't think it's called chrome?)

Comment: Well updating to 13.0.782.218 solved the issue. If anyone feels like answering, i'll accept the answer. (Yeah best practice: update your software manually when you can't do it in an automated fashion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating chrome fixed the issue.
Best practice: update your software.